# Search table by string once found take a different value from that column and return results with that value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to search a table by string and once a value was found I want it to take a different value from the same line but different column as the value and return results with that value.

lets just say I have a column 'names' and a column of 'position' so if the string is 'mark' i want it to find the line that 'mark' is listed on and then take the value from the 'position' and return all the entries with the same position as 'mark'

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume job will be the table and name, position are columns
per your description 'mark' is a name so we need to get the position value for that

```
select name, position
from job
where position=(select position from job where name='mark');
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Join is your friend.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.mark = t2=position
WHERE t1.names = 'bernd';
```